# Replace value in file(web.config) present on another machine(shared folder/network) using C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, automation, shared

I have full access to the file present on another machine and while I type the "\username-txd\abcFolder\Configuration\MediaManagerConfig\Web.config" in run command line I am able to access the above mentioned file but when I try to update the value of any attribute in this particular file it is not allowing me to update.

Code:Piece of impolemented codeC#

when I am passing the value to xmlDoc.Load(@filename);

filename is displayed as the passed value which I want. But as soon as I move ahead with debugging the code, I see my filepath gets appended with "d:/" value.

And filename becomes, filename="D:\username-txd\abcFolder\Configuration\MediaManagerConfig\Web.config"

Why D:// gets appended. Is it referring my local D drive????

Commented lines are some of the option I tried

```
     public void updateFileData()
       {

          private string filename="\\vinayb2txd\\atish\\Configuration\\MediaManagerConfig\\Web.config";   

         private string newElemetValue="qwerty";


         //xmlDoc.Load("\\vinayb2-txd\\atish\\Configuration\\MediaManagerConfig\\Web.config");

    //var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@filename);

   //string serverFilepath= Server.MapPath(@filename);

  // FileStream xmlFile = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);

  // xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile);

  // string abc=new Uri(filename).LocalPath;

        xmlDoc.Load(@filename);
    XmlNodeList elementList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("add");
    for (int i = 0; i < elementList.Count; i++)
    {
        if (elementList[i].Attributes["key"].Value == elementKey)
        {
            elementList[i].Attributes["value"].Value = newElementValue;
            break;
        }
        xmlDoc.Save(filename);
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need four slashes at the start of the filename string for it to be interpreted as a UNC path. Otherwise the double slash is escaped to a single slash, which is interpreted as the root drive of your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
  private string filename="\\\\vinayb2txd\\atish\\Configuration\\MediaManagerConfig\\Web.config";
```

or

```
   private string filename=@"\\vinayb2txd\atish\Configuration\MediaManagerConfig\Web.config";
```

when you define filename as  "\vinayb2txd\atish\Configuration\MediaManagerConfig\Web.config". It takes it as  relative path